# Xamarin Unable to open class file

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Good day all.

I have installed the brand new Visual Studio 2017 with the latest Xamarin.
I have problems opening existing projects but even creating a brand new Cross-Platform App(Xamarin.Forms PCL) I cant even run the app as is? The error is as follow

> "Unable to open class file
>   obj\Debug\android\src\android\support\graphics\drawable\animated\R.java:
>   Permission denied".

But when going to the location above... I can only find up to the point 
obj\Debug\android\src inside the Android project?
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Running VS as admin? Also do you have the file open elsewhere or is shared or in shared folder?

Comment: 1.) Try starting VS as administrator, 2.) try re-building (clean + build OR just rebuild) your solution

Comment: Ok I am not 100% certain what I have done but after hours of "playing" around I by accident deleted my SDK Tools(V25.2.5) and then after many many hours of trying to re-install SDK Tools(v25.2.3) it works again! Thanks so much for your posts!

Answer (score 0):

- Right Click your Android project which is under the Solution Explorer
- Select Properties menu item
- Select Android Options tab
- Uncheck "Use Fast Deployment(debug mode only)"